# Brew install git putting files in .rvm

Tags: git, rvm, homebrew

After running `brew install git`, I got this output:

```
The OS X keychain credential helper has been installed to:
  ~/.rvm/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain

The 'contrib' directory has been installed to:
  ~/.rvm/share/git-core/contrib

Bash completion has been installed to:
  ~/.rvm/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completion has been installed to:
  ~/.rvm/share/zsh/site-functions

==> Summary
  ~/.homebrew/Cellar/git/2.0.0: 1324 files, 31M, built in 46 seconds
```

Is this expected? Why should brew or git be putting anything under rvm (Ruby Version Manager)?

Comment: Taking a peek at the [git recipe](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/git.rb), it installs stuff into `#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}`. I am by no means  an expert, but I think it would be helpful for any would-be answerers if you provided the output of `brew --prefix` and `brew --repository`.

Comment: @MBlanc do you know brew's default prefix? I'm not sure how it got set to .rvm, and I'd like to set it back.

Comment: `/usr/local/` (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MBlanc pointed out,

```
$ brew --prefix
~/.rvm
```